# Converting FAA CPL to EASA

Tags: faa, easa

Hello I currently live in the USA. I hold a CPL with an IR and I am currently in Multi Engine and getting ready for my check ride. I would like to move to Europe and work for airlines there. However I am finding it quite difficult to find anything that helps me or lays out this process. If anyone has any information that can help that would be great. Some of my main questions are:

- How long would this process take?
- Do I have to redo any of my check rides to convert them?
- Is there anywhere here in the USA that with the conversion?
- Is there anyone out there that has done this process?

Any answers help. Thanks.